# Unique constraints on multiple columns that cannot both be null

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, unique-constraint

I wanted to ask if there's a better way of modeling the following behavior in Postgres 10:

```
CREATE TABLE test.my_table
(
    id   UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    id_a UUID,
    id_b UUID,
    some_shared_data JSONB,
    UNIQUE (id_a, id_b)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS b_null_constraint ON test.my_table (id_a) WHERE id_b IS NULL;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS a_null_constraint ON test.my_table (id_b) WHERE id_a IS NULL;

ALTER TABLE test.my_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT both_null_constraint CHECK (
        (id_b IS NOT NULL) OR (id_a IS NOT NULL));
```

I.e. the constraints are:

1. Both `id_a` and `id_b` cannot be `null`
2. The combination of `id_a` and `id_b` must be unique (including cases where one of them is `null`)

It feels to me the code above to set this up is not very expressive. Would people do this in another/more normalized way? I tried splitting this up in separate tables but then constraint (1.) is hard to satisfy.

Comment: This looks just fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this with just two `unique` constraints.  The second one is:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ab_null_constraint ON my_table ( coalesce(id_a, id_b), (id_a is null) WHERE id_a IS NULL or id_b is null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=fa32383fab09d9a70e986dfd2ba49e82) is a db<>fiddle.

Actually, you can combine all this into one unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ab_null_constraint ON
     my_table ( coalesce(id_a, id_b),
                coalesce(id_b, id_a),
                (id_a is null),
                (id_b is null)
              );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2d75a7ac58bfb5e5c9a77fb9d9e5e395) is a db<>fiddle for this.

You might find your original formulation more maintainable.

Comment: Thank you for the input, great to just get another perspective! I think the second example is not that bad actually. One thing I was skeptical about regarding my original solution was that I found it used a lot of different keywords for essentially the same thing. You solution at least sort of fixes that! I think I like it better:)

Comment: @Jonas.z . . . Put a comment next to the index explaining what you want it to do.  It is not obvious (at least to me), and I wrote the code.

Comment: Yes, definitely. I find it useful to partition these migration-type sql files with rigorous documentation. What I liked with your solution is that it's an encapsulated expression for  what's happening. I.e. I can put comments above referring to it directly